# How to parse Date in a String with other text

Tags: java, date

I want to parse the following type of Date in a String, which can contain additional data before and after:

For example: foo-bar_2014-10-14_18.56.05_bar
The following DateFormat doen't work:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd_HH.mm.ss", Locale.ENGLISH);
Date result=df.parse(parent.getName());
```

**Edit:**
Due to the the fact, that the text before and after could be anything like

- house_alarm_2014-10-14_18.56.05_fire
- car-broken_2014-10-14_18.56.05_wheel

I have created a regex which matches the date.

```
    String pattern="\\d\\d\\d\\d[-]\\d\\d[-]\\d\\d[_]\\d\\d.\\d\\d.\\d\\d";
```

Comment: you have always same structure of `_` in the data you get??

Comment: no, it could be anything

Comment: In that case can you please provide some actual examples?

Comment: Some points on your expression: `\\d\\d\\d\\d` can be reduced to `\\d{4}` (the same applies for the rest). You do not need to put `-` within square brackets. Also, you need to escape the period character: `.` needs to become `\\.`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a regexp initially to locate the correct part of the string

```
    String name = "foo-bar_2014-10-14_18.56.05_bar";
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd_HH.mm.ss", Locale.ENGLISH);
    String pattern = "\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}_\\d{2}\\.\\d{2}\\.\\d{2}";
    Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
    Matcher m = r.matcher(name);
    if (m.find()) {
        System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(0));
        Date result = df.parse(m.group(0));
        System.out.println("result: " + result);
    } else {
        System.out.println("NO MATCH");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As the first part (before the date) is not known in advance, I think your only option is to remove the first "unknown" part.

Because the length of the date pattern *is* constant, you can always take the last 19 characters. That might be slightly more efficient than a regular expression, and might also be easier to understand.

Comment: From what I understood, there seems to be no predefined pattern.

Comment: that won work.... what about last `_bar` part? also OP says no predefined pattern....